# Does the specification require from JVM to send of notifications on thread instance when execution of thread ready to be completed?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have read the training for SJCP exam [SCJP 6 Mock exam for Threads](http://nikojava.wordpress.com/2008/09/08/scjp-mock-exam-for-threads/).

By my opinion the answers for the 66 and 67 are incorrect, because the correct answer  for both questions is "c"(The output is not guaranteed to be any of the above).
I belive that "c" is correct answer because it is possible to lose quantum time in point when new thread was started but monitor for new thread was not locked. So, it is really to have situation when execution main thread on CPU will be continued when created thread was done already, so program will hang and nothing will be printed to console. The situation of losing quantum in point above may be simply simulated by insertion Thread.sleep.

But my question is not related to training above. The question related to java.lang.Thread behavior which implemented by OpendJDK 7. If you will run code bellow as is, then you will see 999999 on console.

```
class Job extends Thread {
private Integer number = 0;

public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
        number++;
    }
}

public Integer getNumber() {
    return number;
}
}

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Job thread = new Job();
    thread.start();
    synchronized (thread) {
        thread.wait();
    }
    System.out.println(thread.getNumber());
}
}
```

It is seems to me that implementation of Threads for OpendJDK7 invokes notify(maybe notifyAll) on thread instance when thread execution is ready to be completed. I tried to find any docs related to this behavior(in JMM and javadocs for java.lang.Thread), but I found nothing that help to confirm this fact.

So, my question: Is true that, sending of notify/notifyAll(when thread execution completed)  depends from concrete JRE implementation and is not required by specification?

Comment: If it isn't documented as a specified requirement, it isn't a specified requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's documented in the [documentation of `join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29) (which is the method you should use, instead of `wait()`):

> This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive. As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.

Comment: Thanks, this is a complete answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The wait should always be invoked in a while loop to check for the condition, otherwise you could see spurious wake ups.